# Google Analytics scheduled email reports w/ year over year data

Tags: google-analytics

I've have Analytics set to send a weekly email with the previous 7 days worth of data and the previous years data for comparison. Unfortunately I can only get the previous periods data. I am able to get it to send out a single email with year over year, but all scheduled emails come with the previous periods data.

Has anyone come across this?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: An Analytics tech told me it was a known bug, but didn't give any details on when it might get fixed.